# Работа фрагментов в BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

уже несколько дней борюсь с одной проблемой. У меня есть BottomNavigationView в котором используеться 4 фрагмента. И проблема в том, что когда я переключаюсь между вкладками BottomNavigationView у фрагментов не вызываются методы onPause() и onResume(), то есть каждый фрагмент добавляется как новый, а это может привести к Out Of Memory, и со временем начинает тормозить GUI.
Вот мой код:

```
 BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
 navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.homePage:
                    if (!homePageFragment.isAdded()) {                                     

                     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, homePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("stack");
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.show(homePageFragment);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.youTubePage:
                    if (!youtubePageFragment.isAdded()) {                            
                     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, youtubePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("stack");
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.show(youtubePageFragment);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.videoPage:
                    if (!videoPageFragment.isAdded()) {
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, videoPageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("stack");
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.show(videoPageFragment);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.gamePage:
                    if (!gamePageFragment.isAdded()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, gamePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("stack");
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.show(gamePageFragment);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Подскажите, что я не так делаю. Как сделать так, чтоб я мог оперировать уже добавленными фрагментами, а не чтоб они заново создавались.

Answer (score 1):

Вызывайте не `fragmentTransaction.add`, а `fragmentTransaction.replace` и будет все нормально работать. Будут методы ЖЦ вызываться.
Когда вы вызываете `fragmentTransaction.add`, то у вас все фрагменты друг на друга накладываются.

Comment: Ваш ответ мне не помог(

Comment: Возможно еще у вас проверка на наличие фрагмента неправильная. Попробуйте каждому фрагменту привязать тег. И уже проверять наличие фрагмента с помощью fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag

Comment: И это тоже не помогает findFragmentByTag  всегда возвращает null, даже если фрагмент уже добавлен.

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось исправить ситуацию таким образом:

```
final BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.homePage:
                    if (!homePageFragment.isAdded()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, homePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("home");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(youtubePageFragment).hide(videoPageFragment).hide(gamePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.show(homePageFragment).commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                case R.id.youTubePage:
                    if (!youtubePageFragment.isAdded()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, youtubePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("youtube");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(homePageFragment).hide(videoPageFragment).hide(gamePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.show(youtubePageFragment).commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                case R.id.videoPage:
                    if (!videoPageFragment.isAdded()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, videoPageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("video");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(homePageFragment).hide(youtubePageFragment).hide(gamePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.show(videoPageFragment).commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                case R.id.gamePage:
                    if (!gamePageFragment.isAdded()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_activity_main, gamePageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("game");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    } else {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(homePageFragment).hide(youtubePageFragment).hide(videoPageFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.show(gamePageFragment).commit();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```